# Scraping youtube mix playlist id for a video

Tags: node.js, iframe, heroku, youtube, web-scraping

So here is what I am trying to do:

The app in question that this problem is regarding is here: https://github.com/viperfx/ng-juketube, to give everyone some context. So I am loading a youtube video in the background using the youtube Iframe API giving it a youtube video id. That works well. Next, I want to find out the playlist ID of the youtube mix's that appear sometimes on the sidebar.

Current solution:
I am using nodejs in the backend to scrape the youtube video page, and then look in the sidebar for the string 'Youtube Mix'. When I am running my server locally this works well. However when I am running the app from heroku I do not get the same results (as in a mix does not show up) because I am assuming the youtube server and the IP address I have are affecting youtube mix from showing up.

So my question is how can I obtain the youtube mix playlist id using the client (browser) rather than the server?

I have tried things like trying to load the youtube page as an iframe - does not work. iframes only allowed for /embed*

Answer (score 1):

So here is how I solved this issue.

Using a service called http://www.corsproxy.com/ I was able to scrape youtube and get the playlist id using client side code. Here is a snippet from my code showing the solution:

```
        $.get('http://www.corsproxy.com/www.youtube.com/watch?v='+newVal.videoId,function(response) {
          var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(response, 'text/html');
          $scope.mixId = doc.querySelector('.related-playlist').getAttribute('href').split('list=')[1];
          $scope.$apply();
        });
```